# How to make fortran subroutine results reproducible on R?

Tags: r, fortran, gfortran

I have written a Fortran subroutine:

And I want to implement it on R, so I will do the compile and everything, but I have a question because my fortran subroutine which contains the random number generating process.

This is my fortran subroutine, I use the **random.f90** from [https://jblevins.org/mirror/amiller/random.f90][1] and the **cdflib** from [https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f_src/cdflib/cdflib.html][2]

I use the **random.f90** in my **transform_samples_module**(to use the random normal samples from random.f90 transform them to produce normal samples with specific mean and sd) and **cdfnor** subroutine from **cdflib** in my **getprob1** subroutine

```
subroutine getprob1(n1, mu0, mu1, cv0, cv1, nsim, prob, seed) bind(C, name="getprob1")
    use iso_c_binding
    use random
    use transform_samples_module
    
    implicit none
    ! ---- arg types -----------------------
    integer(c_int), intent(in) :: n1, nsim
    real(c_double), intent(in) :: mu0, mu1, cv0, cv1
    real(c_double), intent(out) :: prob(nsim)
    integer(c_int), intent(in) :: seed

    ! ---------------------------------------
  

    real(c_double) :: sigma0, sigma1
    real(c_double) :: mu_2arm(2), sigma_2arm(2), ybar_2arm(2), var_2arm(2)
    real(c_double), dimension(n1) :: nsamples 
    real(c_double), dimension(n1, 2) :: sample_j
    integer(c_int) :: ite, jj, ii
    real(c_double) :: p, q, x, bound, mean, sd
    integer(c_int) :: status, which
    real(c_double) :: cdf(2), delta(2)

    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

    integer(c_int), dimension(8) :: random_seed_seq

    ! Set the seed
    random_seed_seq = [seed, seed, seed, seed, seed, seed, seed, seed]
    call random_seed(PUT=random_seed_seq)

        
    
    sigma0 = sqrt(log(cv0*cv0 + 1))
    sigma1 = sqrt(log(cv1*cv1 + 1))
    mu_2arm = [mu0, mu1]
    sigma_2arm = [sigma0, sigma1]
    
    do ite = 1, nsim
        
        ybar_2arm = 0.0
        var_2arm = 0.0
  
        
        do jj = 1, 2

    
            call transform_samples(n1, mu_2arm(jj), sqrt(sigma_2arm(jj)), nsamples)
            sample_j(:,jj ) = nsamples    
            ybar_2arm(jj ) = sum(sample_j(:,jj )) / real(n1)
            var_2arm(jj ) = sum((sample_j(:,jj ) - ybar_2arm(jj) )**2) / real(n1 - 1)
          
           
        end do   
        which = 1
        delta = [0.223 , -0.223]
        mean = ybar_2arm(1) - ybar_2arm(2)
        sd = sqrt(var_2arm(1) / real(n1) + var_2arm(2) / real(n1))
        cdf = 0.0
        

        do ii = 1, 2
            x = delta(ii)
            call cdfnor ( which, p, q, x, mean, sd, status, bound )
            if (status /= 0) then
                print *, "Error in cdfnor: status=", status
                stop
            end if
            cdf(ii) = p 
    
        end do
    
        prob(ite) = cdf(1) - cdf(2)


    end do    
    

end subroutine getprob1
```

This is my **transform_samples_module** looks like:

```
module transform_samples_module
    use iso_c_binding
    use random
    implicit none

contains

    subroutine transform_samples(n_samples, desired_mean, desired_stddev, output_samples) bind(C, name="transform_samples")
        integer(c_int), intent(in) :: n_samples
        real(c_double), intent(in) :: desired_mean, desired_stddev
        real(c_double), dimension(n_samples), intent(out) :: output_samples
        real(c_double) :: random_numbers(n_samples)
        integer(c_int) :: i
        
        call random_number(random_numbers)
        random_numbers = sqrt(-2.0d0 * log(random_numbers)) * cos(2.0d0 * 3.141592653589793d0 * random_numbers)
        
        do i = 1, n_samples
            output_samples(i) = desired_mean + desired_stddev * random_numbers(i)
        end do
    end subroutine transform_samples

end module transform_samples_module
```

So I did the compile on R using:

```
library(dotCall64)
# Load the shared library
dyn.load("mylibrary.so")
getprob1 <- function(n1, mu0, mu1, cv0, cv1, nsim, seed) {
  seed <- .Random.seed[-1]  # Exclude the first element of the R random seed
  .C64("getprob1",
       SIGNATURE = c("integer", "double", "double", "double", "double", "integer", "double", "integer"),
       as.integer(n1),
       as.double(mu0),
       as.double(mu1),
       as.double(cv0),
       as.double(cv1),
       as.integer(nsim),
       double(nsim),
       as.integer(seed)
  )[[7]]  # This assumes that the `prob` array is the 7th argument in your Fortran subroutine
}
```

The good thing is that it could run! but what I want to do is that I want it to be able to use the seed in R, for example, if I set.seed(1) in R, it should be able to reproduce the same results. because now I could only do this:

```
> set.seed(1)
> getprob1(34, 1.0, 0.777, 0.5, 0.5, 10, seed = 1)
 [1] 0.8458423 0.7302202 0.6892795 0.4100851 0.7436128 0.5248045 0.5963506 0.6377372 0.2405343 0.3257491
> getprob1(34, 1.0, 0.777, 0.5, 0.5, 10, seed = 1)
 [1] 0.05997150 0.37370831 0.67539986 0.28370543 0.46473538 0.77224209 0.01801777 0.60191086 0.69541114 0.69710732
> set.seed(1)
> getprob1(34, 1.0, 0.777, 0.5, 0.5, 10, seed = 1)
 [1] 0.44087374 0.07380424 0.77093088 0.19258925 0.10651923 0.31367524 0.69142104 0.41027685 0.70321205 0.75460458
> getprob1(34, 1.0, 0.777, 0.5, 0.5, 10, seed = 1)
 [1] 0.52343660 0.83195322 0.68004610 0.19952573 0.33348669 0.09619295 0.27260786 0.62125872 0.28953613 0.71272206
> ## the results will be different even if I set.seed


> ## the below will be the result I want
> set.seed(1)
> get_prob_within(34, 1.0, 0.777, 0.5, 0.5, 10)
 [1] 0.5273274 0.4073686 0.9364763 0.8362440 0.1895381 0.7563707 0.2480652 0.2958896 0.4755769 0.3697152
> get_prob_within(34, 1.0, 0.777, 0.5, 0.5, 10)
 [1] 0.44855057 0.17260087 0.17335768 0.86675369 0.32480827 0.08470480 0.10164869 0.45593050 0.80664073 0.01580556
> set.seed(1)
> get_prob_within(34, 1.0, 0.777, 0.5, 0.5, 10)
 [1] 0.5273274 0.4073686 0.9364763 0.8362440 0.1895381 0.7563707 0.2480652 0.2958896 0.4755769 0.3697152
> get_prob_within(34, 1.0, 0.777, 0.5, 0.5, 10)
 [1] 0.44855057 0.17260087 0.17335768 0.86675369 0.32480827 0.08470480 0.10164869 0.45593050 0.80664073 0.01580556
```

I'm wondering if there is anyway I could do this, I know that Fortran and R use different RNG but I really need to find a way do combined fortran and R.

Thank you for all the help!!
[1]: https://jblevins.org/mirror/amiller/random.f90
[2]: [https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f_src/cdflib/cdflib.html](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/%7Ejburkardt/f_src/cdflib/cdflib.html)

Comment: Tje Fortran code certainly isn't Fortrzn 90, it is at least Fortran 2003. There was no reason for the [tag:fortran90] tag.

Comment: The library in `random.f90` uses the standard Fortran random number generator using `random_number`. You should be able to.set the seed using the associated standard subroutines `random_seed` or `random_init` as already treated in many questions and answers on this site.

Comment: Note that beyond the random numbers issue many of your real constants in your Fortran are of default kind, which is most likely different from that of real variables. This can also lead to reproducibility issues

Comment: You can interface with R's RNG instead of using the one from Fortran, c.f. https://rstudio.github.io/r-manuals/r-exts/The-R-API.html#random-number-generation-from-fortran.